# How to make predictions after every 50 cycles in RSNNS

Tags: r, modeling

I am RSNNS to make a model. I am using QuickProp algorithm. here's my neural network:

```
mydata1 <- read.csv("-1-5_rand1.csv");
mydata <- mydata1[1:151, ]
test_set <- mydata1[152:168, ]
test_set1 <- test_set[c(-7)]
a <- SnnsRObjectFactory()
input <- mydata[c(-7)]
output <- mydata[c(7)]
b <- splitForTrainingAndTest(input, output, ratio = 0.22)
a <- mlp(b$inputsTrain, b$targetsTrain, size = 9, maxit = 650, learnFunc = "Quickprop", learnFuncParams = c(0.01, 2.5, 0.0001, 0, 0), updateFunc = "Topological_Order",
     updateFuncParams = c(0.0), hiddenActFunc = "Act_TanH", computeError=TRUE, initFunc = "Randomize_Weights", initFuncParams = c(-1,1),
     shufflePatterns = TRUE, linOut = FALSE, inputsTest = b$inputsTest, targetsTest = b$targetsTest)
```

I am predicting using test set as:

```
predictions <- predict(a, test_set1)
```

Is it possible to in RSNNS to predict after every 50 cycles using test set instead of predicting after 650 cycles?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe this is possible with `RSNNS` as it doesn't allow you to pass in weights.  You could accomplish this with `nnet` or `neuralnet` packages but I don't know if they contain the specific algorithm you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I checked them, No they don't have Quickprorp.

Answer (score 3):

the answer is you can't do it with the high-level interface, but with the low-level interface, you can have a look, e.g., at the mlp_irisSnnsR.R demo that is included in RSNNS